# insert null into date column in database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've got a gridview in vb.net and am trying to insert a null value into a database column - unfortunately, i keep seeing 1900-01-01 being inserted. below is my code and i need help.

```
Protected Sub gvPOItems_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvPOItems.RowCommand
  If (e.CommandName = "save") Then
   For i As Integer = 0 To gvPOItems.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvPOItems.Rows(i)

    Dim value3 As String = DirectCast(row.Cells(9).FindControl("txtbxExpireDate"), TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3) Or value3.ToString() Is Nothing Then
     value3 = DBNull.Value.ToString()
    End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you store just DBNull.Value ?

Comment: Four things: One, parameterize your SQL. That will solve your problem. Two, is `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3) Or value3.ToString() Is Nothing` necessary? It looks to me like `value3` IS a string, and thus `value3` is equivalent to `value3.ToString()`. Three, what is `DBNull.Value.ToString()`? Four, is your column nullable?

Comment: yes, the column is nullable.  I do the If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3) Or value3.ToString() Is Nothing to check the value and if not a date such as: 8/4/2014 then i want it to be null

Comment: i forgot to add some code in my original post. under the if command = save i do: Dim query As New StringBuilder(). then i put my values into the following:                 query.Append("UPDATE [tblPurchaseDetail] SET [QuantityNewReceived] = '").Append(value1).Append("' , [LotNumber] = '").Append(value2).Append("' , [ExpirationDate] = '").Append(value3).Append("' , [Quantity] = '").Append(value4).Append("' , [PedigreeReceived] = '").Append(value5).Append("' WHERE [PurchaseDetailID] = '").Append(value6).Append("';" & vbLf)
 and pass that as a string to do the updates.

Comment: i have to use: DBNull.Value.ToString() or the code fails

Answer (score 3):

It works when the value isn't null, because you're injecting the value in that string:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (datecolumn) VALUES ('2014-08-04')
```

However, [`DBNull.Value.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t(v=vs.110).aspx) resolves to an empty string. When you then try and insert said empty string into your database via a SQL-injection-prone approach, you're really running a query something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (datecolumn) VALUES ('')
```

And that puts in the default value of `1900-01-01`. What you need is:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (datecolumn) VALUES (NULL)
```

You need to parameterize your queries. Then you can pass `Nothing` directly to your SQL command, and it will work. Aside from that, you have to shift some abstraction so that you only add `'` characters if the argument is **not** `Nothing`, and if it is, then you need to pass the string `NULL`.

---

As for the code you *do* have, there are some bugs here, too.

```
Dim value3 As String = DirectCast(row.Cells(9).FindControl("txtbxExpireDate"), TextBox).Text.Replace("'", "''")
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3) Or value3.ToString() Is Nothing Then
 value3 = DBNull.Value.ToString()
End If
```

`value3` is a `string`, and as per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s(v=vs.110).aspx), `string.ToString()` returns an unconverted instance of the original value. In other words, `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3)` already does what you're checking for in your latter condition, except if the latter condition were ever true it would throw a `NullReferenceException` (or whatever the equivalent of that is in VB, I don't know whether it uses `Nothing` because I've literally never written anything in VB before).

Next, you should be aware that `value3` will *never* be `Nothing`. It comes directly from a `TextBox.Text` property, and will consequently be *at most* an empty string. That's fine, because you check for that in `IsNullOrEmpty`, but since you added on the `Is Nothing` I thought I'd better point that out.

So basically, long story short, **parameterize your queries.** For all our sakes. But if you absolutely aren't going to, this should fix this particular problem:

```
Dim value3 As String = DirectCast(row.Cells(9).FindControl("txtbxExpireDate"), TextBox).Text
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value3)
    value3 = "NULL"
Else
    value3 = "'" + value3.Replace("'", "''") + "'"
End If
```

You'll then have to adjust your later code to not add in those quotes, itself.